# Detox - How to close Android soft keyboard?

Tags: android-softkeyboard, detox

How to close soft keyboard on Android?

In source there is a [`closeSoftKeyboard`](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/38644af6809a0bde7f130fe5deda9a0c339423e6/detox/src/android/espressoapi/ViewActions.js#L149) inside the `ViewActions.js`, what's that? I don't see that is available through the API. Can I use it somehow?
If not, what's the recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: So, did `closeSoftwareKeyboard` work?

Comment: In essence, closeSoftKeyboard is a JS-mirror of the equivalent method implemented by Espresso, but it's not available through Detox' API. Could please describe the scenario better - what makes this needed to begin with?

Comment: @d4vidi how do I call this method ?

Comment: Have you tried using `device.pressBack()`?